# Replace string in a huge (70GB), one line, text file

Tags: text-processing, sed, large-files

I have a huge (70GB), **one line**, text file and I want to replace a string (token) in it. 
I want to replace the token `<unk>`, with another dummy token ([glove issue](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe/issues/32)).

I tried `sed`:

```
sed 's/<unk>/<raw_unk>/g' < corpus.txt > corpus.txt.new
```

but the output file `corpus.txt.new` has zero-bytes!

I also tried using perl:

```
perl -pe 's/<unk>/<raw_unk>/g' < corpus.txt > corpus.txt.new
```

but I got an out of memory error.

For smaller files, both of the above commands work.

How can I replace a string is such a file?
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171901/sed-command-find-and-replace-in-file-and-overwrite-file-doesnt-work-it-empties) is a related question, but none of the answers worked for me.

**Edit**:
What about splitting the file in chunks of 10GBs (or whatever) each and applying `sed` on each one of them and then merging them with `cat`? Does that make sense? Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: as @Gilles noted, can you detect some repeated character that could serve as a custom delimiter in your single big line?

Comment: I am thinking that a tool that can only do search and replace, but not any more complex regex, would be faster. It would also not benefit from doing a line at a time, so would not choke on this file. Unfortunately I have no idea of the existence of such a tool, though it would not be hard to write. If it is a one off then substituting in newline characters as in one of the answers would probably be easiest.

Comment: Does your file contain anything other than ASCII? If so, all the unicode handling could be omitted and raw bytes could be processed.

Comment: I agree with @PatrickButcher Look at a bigger picture. Besides the immediate need to replace this text, what else is this file supposed to be used for? If it is a log of some sort, no one is going to be able to work with it effectively. If it is a data file that some app uses, then that app should hold the responsibility for maintaining the data in that file.

Comment: @ThomasCarlisle: The huge file is a [GloVe](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe) corpus, but I'm still not 100% sure what GloVe actually does. I think it might be useful for natural language processing: teaching computers to analyze plain-English text and to understand what the text really means. GloVe is useful for training and using [word embeddings](http://enwp.org/Word_embedding). See also [a related Quora post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-definition-of-word-embedding-word-representation) and [a relevant blog post](http://veredshwartz.blogspot.co.il/2016/01/representing-words.html).

Comment: @ThomasCarlisle: GloVe is related to [Word2vec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec).

Comment: Your example replacement is `s/<unk>/<raw_unk>/`.  If you could use `rnk` rather than `raw_unk`, you could edit the file in-place with a simple C program - which would avoid having to write out 70GB (of course, you *would* still need to read 70GB, and if the `<unk>` occurs frequently, you end up rewriting most of the file anyway.

Comment: In case you have easy access to a Mac system, [Hex Fiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend) is designed for editing huge files.

Comment: You can use `split` with `-b` option defining chunk file sizes in bytes. Process each in turn using `sed` and the re-assemble. There is a risk is that `<unk>` can be split in two files and won't be found...

Comment: @VladislavsDovgalecs, good idea!  For the problem you mention, maybe a sliding window will address it (for example, checking files split on 0-, 1-, 2-, 3-, and 4-aligned boundaries quintuples the work, but prevents a possible miss); or else, more economically, just giving special processing to any chunk (and its successor) that ends with any initial substring of `<unk>`?

Comment: Is this an XML file? In that case, there are XML parsers that can do manipulations on XML streams...

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The usual text processing tools are not designed to handle lines that don't fit in RAM. They tend to work by reading one record (one line), manipulating it, and outputting the result, then proceeding to the next record (line).

If there's an ASCII character that appears frequently in the file and doesn't appear in `<unk>` or `<raw_unk>`, then you can use that as the record separator. Since most tools don't allow custom record separators, swap between that character and newlines. `tr` processes bytes, not lines, so it doesn't care about any record size. Supposing that `;` works:

```
<corpus.txt tr '\n;' ';\n' |
sed 's/<unk>/<raw_unk>/g' |
tr '\n;' ';\n' >corpus.txt.new
```

You could also anchor on the first character of the text you're searching for, assuming that it isn't repeated in the search text and it appears frequently enough. If the file may start with `unk>`, change the sed command to `sed '2,$ s/…` to avoid a spurious match.

```
<corpus.txt tr '\n<' '<\n' |
sed 's/^unk>/raw_unk>/g' |
tr '\n<' '<\n' >corpus.txt.new
```

Alternatively, use the last character.

```
<corpus.txt tr '\n>' '>\n' |
sed 's/<unk$/<raw_unk/g' |
tr '\n>' '>\n' >corpus.txt.new
```

Note that this technique assumes that sed operates seamlessly on a file that doesn't end with a newline, i.e. that it processes the last partial line without truncating it and without appending a final newline. It works with GNU sed. If you can pick the last character of the file as the record separator, you'll avoid any portability trouble.

Comment: I don't have such a file to test with, but in Awk you can specify the "Record Separator" and the "Output Record Separator".  So assuming you have a decent smattering of commas in your file, it's possible you could solve this with: `awk -v RS=, -v ORS=, '{gsub(/<unk>/, "<raw_unk>"); print}'`  No?

Comment: @Wildcard Yes, that's another solution. Awk tends to be slower than sed though, that's why I don't offer it as the preferred solution for a huge file.

Comment: You can set the record separator in Perl with command line option `-0` and the octal value of a char, or inside the script it can be set with special variable `$/`

Comment: @Gilles : But using `awk` avoid passing the stream twice to `tr`. So would it be still slower ?

Comment: @user285259 Typically not. `tr` is very fast and the pipe can even be parallelized.

Comment: i've never used `tr` before and only a little `sed`. if the `gawk` solution is a little more easy to read/understand, maybe post the `gawk` solution in the comments.

Comment: Sorry, but why not just using `tr` directly to solve the problem? I mean what's wrong with `tr "<unk>" "<raw_unk>"`?

Comment: @jena `tr` changes single characters. This command changes all `u` to `r`, all `n` to `a`, all `k` to `w` and all `>` to `_`. It's impossible to replace a specific multi-character string with `tr`.

Comment: Oh I see, I forgot about that, thanks.

Answer (score 116):

For such a big file, one possibility is Flex. Let `unk.l` be:

```
%%
\<unk\>     printf("<raw_unk>");  
%%
```

Then compile and execute:

```
$ flex -o unk.c  unk.l
$ cc -o unk -O2 unk.c -lfl
$ unk < corpus.txt > corpus.txt.new
```

Comment: `make` has default rules for this, instead of the flex/cc you can add an `%option main` as the first line of unk.l and then just `make unk`.  I more-or-less reflexively use `%option main 8bit fast`, and have `export CFLAGS='-march=native -pipe -Os'` in my `.bashrc`.

Comment: @undercat: If it weren't off-topic, I could show you a number of non-compiler front end applications, from solving the water-level problem to special-purpose input parsing.  It's amazing what you can do with it, if you think outside the box a bit :-)

Comment: @jthill, thank you: `%option main` + `make` + optionally `CFLAGS` are a very nice trick!!  Is `-march=native` the default behaviour?

Comment: @jamesqf, I feel the same and I am curious about your point of view and message: why not writing a new question to specifically raise that topic?

Comment: @JJoao: I'm not sure how such a question could be worded.  "What interesting non compiler frontend things can you do with flex?" perhaps.

Comment: @jamesqf as you said - will be hard to make that an on topic question - but I would like to see it also

Comment: @jamesqf A prof of mine at uni used flex to build a tool that recognised fabric types for a factory! How about asking something like: "flex seems like a very powerful tool but I'm unlikely to be writing any compilers/parsers - are there any other use cases for flex?"

Answer (score 41):

So you don't have enough *physical* memory (RAM) to hold the whole file at once, but on a 64-bit system you have enough *virtual* address space to map the entire file.  Virtual mappings can be useful as a simple hack in cases like this.

The necessary operations are all included in Python.  There are several annoying subtleties, but it does avoid having to write C code.  In particular, care is needed to avoid copying the file in memory, which would defeat the point entirely.  On the plus side, you get error-reporting for free (python "exceptions") :).

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3
# This script takes input from stdin
# (but it must be a regular file, to support mapping it),
# and writes the result to stdout.

search = b'<unk>'
replace = b'<raw_unk>'


import sys
import os
import mmap

# sys.stdout requires str, but we want to write bytes
out_bytes = sys.stdout.buffer

mem = mmap.mmap(sys.stdin.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
i = mem.find(search)
if i < 0:
    sys.exit("Search string not found")

# mmap object subscripts to bytes (making a copy)
# memoryview object subscripts to a memoryview object
# (it implements the buffer protocol).
view = memoryview(mem)

out_bytes.write(view[:i])
out_bytes.write(replace)
out_bytes.write(view[i+len(search):])
```

Comment: If My system has about 4 gb consequite memory free out of the 8 gb, does mem = mmap.mmap(sys.stdin.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ) mean that it place the data in that space?  Or would it be much lower (1gb?)>

Comment: @Rahul "So you don't have enough RAM, but on a 64-bit system you have enough *virtual* address space to map the entire file."  It's paged in and out of physical ram on demand (or lack thereof).  This program should work without requiring any large amount of physical RAM.  64-bit systems have much more virtual address space than the maximum physical ram.  Also each running process has it's own virtual address space.  This means the system as a whole running out of virtual address space isn't a thing, it's not a valid concept.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to understand from this example how the os will decide regarding memory allocation when we use this python method. I understand now, its just same a typical executable.  The same range of memory, hence no limitation or optimizations.  I am not familiar with memory mapping in python.  Thank you for the exaplanation.

Comment: @Rahul yep!  python mmap.mmap() is a fairly thin wrapper around the C function mmap().  And mmap() is the same mechanism used to run executables, and code from shared libraries.

Comment: But why would one want to avoid writing C?  For this, it's no more difficult (assuming a knowedge of both languages) than Python, and perhaps a bit more compact.

Comment: @jamesqf I could be wrong, but I feel it is just a personal choice.  Since the performance losses would be negligible (because as he said, the function actual does call the c function), the overhead wastage is very low, since no other stuff is happening in between.  C would have been better, but this solution was not aiming for optimization, just to solve the bigger and difficult 70gb issue.

Comment: In general, writing in python is more compact.  In this case it turned out there's a couple of details in the python version, and the C version might have been nicer to write.  (Though it's not so simple if `search` can contain a NUL character.  And I notice the other C version here does not support NUL characters in `replace`.).  You're very welcome to derive the C version for comparison purposes.  However remember that my version includes basic error reporting for the operations it performs.  The C version would at least be more annoying to _read_ IMO, when error reporting is included.

Comment: @Rahul: Sure, it's personal choice, but I don't think "to avoid writing in C" is a good basis for that choice.  Especially if one happens to be fluent in C.  Indeed, I'd probably use C to avoid writing in Python :-)

Comment: @jamesqf I respect your opinion, and also that of op.  When I answered your comment, the context was my comment - regarding memory space and how a c function was wrapped.  Hence my response.  When I read this response of yours, I did read the answer again, and understood the context you quote.  I had not responded to that.  So, I withdraw. I think the conversation was between you two, and I meddled, sorry for that to both of you.  And also, I dont know deep c or python, I am studying :)

Comment: @jamesqf: I'm unaware of a standard libc function that searches arbitrary byte sequences in raw memory, i. e. disregarding any NUL termination characters. Of course we can roll our own, but that's going to be at least one of slow (with a naive algorithm) or error prone (for an efficient algorithm). Python’s `find` function on buffer-like objects is supposedly well tested and implements a sensible search algorithm like Boyer-Moore.

Answer (score 17):

There is a `replace` utility in the mariadb-server/mysql-server package. It replaces simple strings (not regular expressions) and unlike grep/sed/awk `replace` does not care about `\n` and `\0`. Memory consumption is constant with any input file (about 400kb on my machine).

Of course you do not need to run a mysql server in order to use `replace`, it is only packaged that way in Fedora. Other distros/operating systems may have it packaged separately.

Answer (score 16):

I think the C version might perform much better:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PAT_LEN 5

int main()
{
    /* note this is not a general solution. In particular the pattern
     * must not have a repeated sequence at the start, so <unk> is fine
     * but aardvark is not, because it starts with "a" repeated, and ababc
     * is not because it starts with "ab" repeated. */
    char pattern[] = "<unk>";          /* set PAT_LEN to length of this */
    char replacement[] = "<raw_unk>"; 
    int c;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF;) {
        if (c == pattern[i]) {
            i++;
            if (i == PAT_LEN) {
                printf("%s", replacement);
                i = 0;
            }
        } else {
            if (i > 0) {
                for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    putchar(pattern[j]);
                }
                i = 0;
            }
            if (c == pattern[0]) {
                i = 1;
            } else {
                putchar(c);
            }
        }
    }
    /* TODO: fix up end of file if it ends with a part of pattern */
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Modified according to suggestions from the comments. Also fixed bug with the pattern `<<unk>`.

Comment: I measured 0.3 seconds for 30 megabytes, so it could be done within 12 minutes.

Comment: you may print (pattern[j]) instead of (buf[j]) (they are equal at this point, so you don't need buffer

Comment: also code will not work for string "<<unk>" https://ideone.com/ncM2yy

Comment: If you want to do it efficiently, doing binary read/writes and asynchronous I/O would probably help.

Comment: 30 MB in 0.3 seconds?  That's only 90 MB / second.  `memcpy` speed (i.e. the memory bottleneck) is something like 12GB / second on a recent x86 CPU (e.g. Skylake).  Even with stdio + system call overhead, for a 30MB file hot in disk cache, I'd expect maybe 1GB / second for an efficient implementation.  Did you compile with optimization disabled, or is one-char-at-a-time I/O really that slow?  `getchar_unlocked` / `putchar_unlocked` might help, but definitely better to read/write in chunks of maybe 128kiB (half of L2 cache size on most x86 CPUs, so you mostly hit in L2 while looping after read)

Comment: from top of my head, getchar and putchar *is* slow.

Comment: The `fix` to the program for `"<<unk>"` still doesn't work if the `pattern` starts with a repeated sequence of characters (i.e. it wouldn't work if you were trying to replace aardvark with zebra and you had input of aaardvak, or you were trying to replace ababc and had input of abababc). In general  you can not move forward by the number of characters you have read unless you know that there is no possibility of a match starting in the characters you have read.

Comment: @icarus: Sure, the program only works for the pattern `<unk>`. It's not a general solution to a substitution problem, it's a solution for the very specific problem at hand.

Comment: All these bugs is why writing it in python was the better choice. Premature optimization is the root of all evil and the hallmark of an inexperienced engineer!

Answer (score 14):

GNU `grep` can show you the offset of matches in "binary" files, without having to read whole lines into memory. You can then use `dd` to read up to this offset, skip over the match, then continue copying from the file.

```
file=...
newfile=...
replace='<raw_unk>'
grep -o -b -a -F '<unk>' <"$file" |
(   pos=0
    while IFS=$IFS: read offset pattern
    do size=${#pattern}
       let skip=offset-pos
       let big=skip/1048576
       let skip=skip-big*1048576
       dd bs=1048576 count=$big <&3
       dd bs=1 count=$skip <&3
       dd bs=1 count=$size of=/dev/null <&3
       printf "%s" "$replace"
       let pos=offset+size
    done
    cat <&3
) 3<"$file" >"$newfile"
```

For speed, I've split the `dd` into a big read of blocksize 1048576 and a smaller read of 1 byte at a time, but this operation will still be a little slow on such a large file. The `grep` output is, for example, `13977:<unk>`, and this is split on the colon by the read into variables `offset` and `pattern`. We have to keep track in `pos` of how many bytes have already been copied from the file.

Answer (score 11):

Here is another single UNIX command line that might perform better than other options, because you can "hunt" for a "block size" that performs well.   For this to be robust you need to know that you have at least one space in every X characters, where X is your arbitrary "block size".  In the example below I have chosen a "block size" of 1024 characters.

```
fold -w 1024 -s corpus.txt | sed 's/<unk>/<raw_unk>/g' | tr '/n' '/0'
```

Here, fold will grab *up to* 1024 bytes, but the -s makes sure it breaks on a space if there is at least one since the last break.

The sed command is yours and does what you expect.

Then the tr command will "unfold" the file converting the newlines that were inserted back to nothing.

You should consider trying larger block sizes to see if it performs faster.  Instead of 1024, you might try 10240 and 102400 and 1048576 for the -w option of fold.

Here is an example broken down by each step that converts all the N's to lowercase:

```
[root@alpha ~]# cat mailtest.txt
test XJS C4JD QADN1 NSBN3 2IDNEN GTUBE STANDARD ANTI UBE-TEST EMAIL*C.34X test

[root@alpha ~]# fold -w 20 -s mailtest.txt
test XJS C4JD QADN1
NSBN3 2IDNEN GTUBE
STANDARD ANTI
UBE-TEST
EMAIL*C.34X test

[root@alpha ~]# fold -w 20 -s mailtest.txt | sed 's/N/n/g'
test XJS C4JD QADn1
nSBn3 2IDnEn GTUBE
STAnDARD AnTI
UBE-TEST
EMAIL*C.34X test

[root@alpha ~]# fold -w 20 -s mailtest.txt | sed 's/N/n/g' | tr '\n' '\0'
test XJS C4JD QADn1 nSBn3 2IDnEn GTUBE STAnDARD AnTI UBE-TEST EMAIL*C.34X test
```

You will need to add a newline to the very end of the file if it has one, because the tr command will remove it.

Comment: How do you make sure you are not breaking the pattern in edge cases where there isn't enough whitespace available?

Comment: As stated, for this to be robust there's a requirement that there is at least one space every X characters.  You can do that analysis easy enough, with any blocksize you choose:

fold -w X mailtest.txt | grep -v " " | wc -l

The number it returns is the number of folded lines with potential edge cases.  If it's zero, the solution is guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 10):

## Using `perl`

### Managing your own buffers

You can use `IO::Handle`'s `setvbuf` to manage the default buffers, or you can manage your own buffers with `sysread` and `syswrite`. Check `perldoc -f sysread` and `perldoc -f syswrite` for more information, essentially they skip buffered io.

Here we roll our own buffer IO, but we do it manually and arbitrarily on 1024 bytes. We also open the file for RW so we do it all on the same FH at once.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Fcntl qw(:flock O_RDWR);
use autodie;
use bytes;

use constant CHUNK_SIZE => 1024 * 32;

sysopen my $fh, 'file', O_RDWR;
flock($fh, LOCK_EX);

my $chunk = 1;
while ( sysread $fh, my $bytes, CHUNK_SIZE * $chunk ) {
  if ( $bytes =~ s/<unk>/<raw_unk>/g ) {
    seek( $fh, ($chunk-1)* CHUNK_SIZE, 0 );
    syswrite( $fh, $bytes, 1024);
    seek( $fh, $chunk * CHUNK_SIZE, 0 );
  }
  $chunk++;
}
```

If you're going to go this route

1. Make sure `<unk>` and `<raw_unk>` are the same byte size.
2. You may want to make sure our buffered method doesn't cross the `CHUNKSIZE` boundary, if you're replacing more than 1 byte.

Comment: What if `<unk>` falls on a boundary between chunks?

Answer (score 10):

You could try ***bbe*** ([binary block editor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bbe-/)), a "`sed` for binary files".

I had good success using it on a 7GB text file with no `EOL` chars, replacing multiple occurrences of a string with one of different length. Without attempting any optimisation it gave an average processing throughput of > 50MB/s.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a small Go program that performs the task (`unk.go`):

```go
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    const (
        pattern     = "<unk>"
        replacement = "<raw_unk>"
    )
    var match int
    var char rune
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        char = rune(scanner.Text()[0])
        if char == []rune(pattern)[match] {
            match++
            if match == len(pattern) {
                fmt.Print(replacement)
                match = 0
            }
        } else {
            if match > 0 {
                fmt.Print(string(pattern[:match]))
                match = 0
            }
            if char == rune(pattern[0]) {
                match = 1
            } else {
                fmt.Print(string(char))
            }
        }
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Just build it with `go build unk.go` and run it as `./unk <input >output`.

## EDIT:

Sorry, I didn't read that everything is in one line, so I tried to read the file character by character now.

## EDIT II:

Applied same fix as to the C program.

Comment: does this avoid reading the entire file into memory?

Comment: It reads the file character by character and never holds the _entire_ file in the memory, just individual characters.

Comment: `scanner.Split(bufio.ScanRunes)` does the magic.

Comment: Also check `go doc bufio.MaxScanTokenSize` for the default buffer size.

Comment: Like your `C` program, this doesn't work for replacing aardvark with zebra with an input of aaardvark.

Comment: @icarus: As stated in the comment to the C program, the program only deals with the one specific substitution of `<unk>`. Other patterns require a different logic.

Answer (score 5):

With `perl`, you could work with fixed length records like:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{$/=\1e8}
          s/<unk>/<raw_unk>/g' < corpus.txt > corpus.txt.new
```

And hope that there won't be `<unk>`s spanning across two of those 100MB records.

Comment: I also was thinking about this method, but using the `while read -N 1000 chunk;` (the `1000` picked as an example). The solution for the `<unk>`, broken between the chunks, is two passes through the file: the first with the 100MB chunks and the second with the '100MB + 5 byte' chunks. But it is not optimal solution in the case of the 70GB file.

Comment: You don't even need two passes. Read block A. While not EOF, read block B. Search/Replace in A+B. A := B. Loop. Complexity is ensuring you don't replace inside the replacement.

Comment: @MiniMax, that second pass would not necessarily help as the first pass would have added 5 bytes for each occurrence of `<unk>`.

Comment: @roaima, yes that would be a much more involved solution. Here it's a simple approach which is only highly probable (assuming the `<unk>` occurrences are far appart, if not, use `$/ = ">"` and `s/<unk>\z/<raw_unk>/g`) of being correct.

Answer (score 1):

This may be overkill for a 70GB file and simple search & replace, but the Hadoop MapReduce framework would solve your problem right now at no cost (choose the 'Single Node' option when setting it up to run it locally) - and will can be scaled to infinite capacity in the future without the need to modify your code.

The official tutorial at https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html uses (extremely simple) Java but you can find client libraries for Perl or whatever language you feel like using.

So if later on you find that you are doing more complex operations on 7000GB text files - and having to do this 100 times per day - you can distribute the workload across multiple nodes that you provision or that are automatically provisioned for you by a cloud-based Hadoop cluster.

Comment: yes, yes it is.  ["Don't use Hadoop - your data isn't that big"](https://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2013/hadoop_hatred.html).  This is a very simple streaming IO problem.

Answer (score 0):

If we have a minimum amount of `<unk>` (as expected by Zipf's law),

```
awk -v RS="<unk>" -v ORS="<raw_unk>" 1
```

Comment: No. `sed` reads a line at a time into memory regardless. It will not be able to fit this line.

Comment: I can find no documentation that says anything other than that GNU `sed` will not do input/output _buffering_ when using this flag. I can't see that it will read partial lines.

Comment: this awk, not sed -> upvoting

Answer (score 0):

All of the previous suggestions require reading the entire file and writing the entire file. This not only takes a long time but also requires 70GB of free space.

1) If I understand you specific case correctly would it be acceptable to replace <unk> with some other string of the SAME length?

2a) Are there multiple occurrences? 
2b) If so do you know how many?

I'm sure you have solved this year-plus problem already and I'd like to know what solution you used.

I'd propose a solution (most likely in C ) that would read the BLOCKS of the file searching each for the string taking into account possible block crossing. Once found replace the string with the SAME length alternate and the write only that BLOCK. Continuing for the known number of occurrences or until end of file. This would require as few as number-of-occurances writes and at most twice that (if every occurrence was split between 2 blocks). This would require NO additional space!